# How to ensure data return after promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have started recently on Ionic and it requires a good grasp of AngularJS, which has some things I do not understand yet.

Basically, I have a search field, where I bind the property formdata.searchText and trigger the search function each time the value is changed. The callback is a collection of artists that fill my list.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="formdata.searchText" placeholder="Search" 
ng-change="search()">
```

In my controller, this property is defined and on change, the method search gets called. Search reaches out to the factory for an API call.

```
.controller('SearchController', function($scope, SpotifyFactory) {

 $scope.formdata = [{
    searchText: ""
  }];

 $scope.search = function(){
     $scope.searchResults = SpotifyFactory.searchArtist($scope.formdata.searchText);
  };  
})
```

This works well so far. The call is being made to the Spotify API and it returns the results of found artists based on my searchterm.

My data:

[image: 1]

When I console.log the $scope.searchResults in my controller, it contains my desired values. But I believe that happens because console.log is being executed after a the promise is done, which makes it possible for the data to be displayed. If I console.log the object in my controller, and say for example

```
console.log($scope.searchResults.artists);
```

It returns an undefined, while Im still able to access the other properties.

Below is how I make the API call in the factory.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('SpotifyFactory', function($http){        

    var foundArtists = function($searchTerm) {

        var baseUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=" + $searchTerm + "&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20";
        var searchResults = [];

        searchResults.$promise = $http.get(baseUrl).then(function(response){
            angular.copy(response.data, searchResults);
            return searchResults;
        });

        return searchResults;
    }

    return {
        searchArtist : foundArtists
    }
  }
)
```

My question is, how can I ensure that the data gets returned, after the call of the API is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a promise

```
.factory('SpotifyFactory', function($http){        

    var foundArtists = function ($searchTerm) { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 

        var baseUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=" + $searchTerm + "&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20";
        var searchResults = [];

        searchResults.$promise = $http.get(baseUrl).then(function(response){
            angular.copy(response.data, searchResults);
            resolve(searchResults);
        });
    }});

    return {
        searchArtist : foundArtists
    }
  }
```

Then call it from where you want

```
SpotifyFactory.searchArtist('madonna').then((data) {

$log.info('Data retrieved!', data);
// do things you want to do after results are found
}).catch( ... error function);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That was exactly what I was looking for! I still don't have the privilege to upvote it, but once I have enough points, I'll do so!

Comment: @user3672317 you're welcome, this is a common usage of an angular factory and Promises are everywhere today ;)